# call a static method on a parameter while using @CacheResult

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, jcache, jsr107

I need to cache the result of a method that call a webservice.
The method signature is like this :

```
public Result search(long id, String name, Date date);
```

and the result depends on all the parameters

I created the ehcache configuration  for the cache `myCache`, normally to use this cache I should use the `@CacheResult` annotation :

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "myCache")
public Result search(long id, String name, Date date);
```

But in my case I need to call a static method on the `date` parameter, I want to do it the same way as the `@Cacheable` annotation :

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key ="{#id, #name, T(my.static).method(#date)}")
public Result search(long id, String name, Date date);
```

My question is how could I call a static method on a parameter while using  `@CacheResult` ?

Answer (score 0):

`@CacheResult` supplies a way to customize the generated key by defining a key generator class like this:

```
@CacheResult(cacheKeyGenerator = CustomKeyGenerator.class)
public Result search(long id, String name, Date date);
```

It does not support definition of key generation in terms of SpEL evaluation directly in the annotation; instead you must provide your own implementation of `javax.cache.annotation.CacheKeyGenerator`:

```
public class CustomKeyGenerator implements CacheKeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public GeneratedCacheKey generateCacheKey(CacheKeyInvocationContext<? extends Annotation> cacheKeyInvocationContext) {
        CacheInvocationParameter[] parameters = cacheKeyInvocationContext.getKeyParameters();
        // calculate a key based on parameters
        return new SearchKey();
    }
```